# Is there a family of lines having two (or more) distinct envelopes?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, algebraic-geometry

**The question:**

It's on the title. It just needs some clarification:

$i)$ The problem takes place in the real plane.

$ii)$ The "envelope" has its definition of the $E_2$ in this Wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_%28mathematics%29#Alternative_definitions.

Also, tangents in the definition are **really** tangents, not asymptotes.

$iii)$ "Distinct" does not exclude intersection.

$iv)$ The family of lines is continuous.

$\text{}$

This problem is posed by myself out of curiosity. I believe there is a significant amount of the satisfying families, but I haven't found any so far.

Thanks in advance!!!

$\text{}$

**Update:** It would be perfect if the (at least) two envelopes had distinct "shapes" as well. However, it's still satisfying otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, accept in the trivial case (where all lines are the same).

Let $F_t(x,y) = a(t) x + b(t)y + c(t)$ be a familly of lines (assume $(a(t),b(t)) \neq (0,0)$ for each $t$), and $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ be two distinct solutions of
$$F_t(\gamma(t))=0~, \quad \partial_t F_t(\gamma(t)) =0.$$
We have $\gamma_1(t) \neq \gamma_2(t)$ for $t$ in some interval $I$. But the equation $F_t=\partial_t F_t=0$ has at least 2 solutions iff $F_t$ and $\partial_t F_t$ are colinear, i.e. there exists $\lambda(t)$ such that $\partial_t F_t = \lambda(t) F_t $, i.e. $a,b,c$ are solutions of
$$ u'(t)=\lambda(t) u(t)$$
But since the space of solution is of dimension $1$, one can write $(a,b,c)=(\alpha u_0,\beta u_0,\gamma u_0)$ with $u_0$ nowhere zero, i.e. $F_t \equiv \alpha x + \beta y + \gamma$ (at least when $t \in I$).

Comment: I'm considering your solution. Also, I've updated the question, which probably doesn't affect your solution. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both arcs of the hyperbola are envelopes in the sense of $E_2$ to its two asymptotes.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood something because each arc of a hyperbola is not an envelope (in the sense of $E_2$) for the whole family of lines, and if we halve the family, only one of the arcs becomes an envelope of the halved family.

Comment: Indeed. I removed the second sentence. The first remains true.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you mean that the family of lines includes **just** the two asymptotes?

Comment: Yes. It is not required that any point of the curves is tangent to any line. It is only needed that the curve is tangent to all lines.

Comment: But I don't think asymptotes are counted as proper tangents. Also, it contradicts my update $iv)$. I'll update about the proper "tangency".